# How to adjust a text in a sideways table column?

Tags: tables, rotating, text

I have this sideways table (in the attached image) and I would like to "adjust" the text in the columns. I can see that it is centered but when I attempt to just leave it un-centered, it does not work! ALso, the last column does not accept centering as well. Is there a way for adjusting the texts inside the columns?

The code im using for the table is:

```
\begin{sidewaystable} 
\caption{ Space Missions dedicated to measure atmospheric chemical compositions with their specifications. }
\begin{tabular} {p{5cm} >{\centering}p{4cm} >{\centering} p{4cm} >{\centering} p{4cm} p{3.5cm} } 
\firsthline
\hline 
\\[-2ex]
\textbf {\backslashbox[7.5em]  {Parameter} {HSI\kern-1.5em\\  Imager\kern-2em}} & \textbf{TANSO\\GOSAT} & \textbf {HSI\\OCO-2} & \textbf {SCIAMACHY\\ENVISAT} & \textbf {TSCS, TanSat} \\
\hline
%\rowcolor{Gray}

Spectral Range &  760 – 15,000 nm & 3 different independent bands: 760 nm, 1600 nm and 2000 nm  &    214 -2380 nm    &   3 different independent bands: 760 nm, 1600 nm and 2000 nm  \\ 

Spectral Resolution\\Resolving Power &  0.2 \(cm^{-1}\)  & 20,000 (resolving Power) FWHM=0.08nm) for \coo \@ bands & 0.2nm – 1.5nm.
(1000-10000 resolving power)
  &0.614  \\ 
%
 Spatial Resolution   &   Swath= 750 km, IFOV= 10.5 km (15.8 mrad).    & Swath= 10.3 km IFOV= 1.3 km cross-track, 2.25 km along-track. (Nadir). & Swath= 240km
IFOV= 30km × 60km for Nadir.
& 0.081 nm for \ch{O2} band, 0.12 nm for the W\coo and 0.16 nm for S\coo. 12,000 resolving power  \\ 

 Observation Mode&Nadir-looking& Nadir, Glint, Target & Nadir, Limb, and Occultation &0.614  \\ 
%\rowcolor{Gray}
 SNR & $>$300& 250 to 450 for the \ch{O2} A-band, 400 to 800 for the  W\coo\@, and 200 to 500 for the S\coo & $>$1000 &360 (\ch{O2} band), 250 (W\coo), 180 (S\coo2). \\ 

Accuracy& 1\% (~4ppm) for \coo & ~0.3 to 0.5\% (1 to 2 ppm) for \coo  & N/A &   1\% (~4ppm) for \coo  \\ 
%\rowcolor{Gray}
 Mass &1& 0.999 &0.710& 180 kg  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\label{table2.2}
\end{sidewaystable}
```

[image]

Many thanks

Edit & Clarification:

The document class I am using is:
`\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`. The `\backslashbox` is in the preamble with package `\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}`.

Packages:

```
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage[breaklinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{a4paper,inner=3cm, outer=3cm, top=3cm, bottom=3cm}
\pdfpagewidth=\paperwidth
\pdfpageheight=\paperheight
\usepackage{fancyvrb,cprotect}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{chemformula}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{diagbox}

\usepackage{longtable, tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.9}
\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{slashbox,pict2e}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Comment: Please clarify the meanings of "leave it un-centered" and "it does not work". Which document class do you employ? Which packages have to be loaded to make your code compilable? How or where is `\backslashbox` defined?

Comment: Hi @Mico, sorry for not being clear! Ive clarified it in the edit section in the question. What i meant by 'does not work' when I insert a '>{\centering} ' at the last column is that it throws an error complaining about the '\hline' at the end of the head row! The \hline has to be there and not to be removed!

Comment: you can use `\centering\arraybackslash`  to avoid the error

Comment: don't post disconnected fragments, post a small complete document, include only the packages needed for the example.